# Necesito crear una string diferente para cada activity?

Tags: android-studio, android-layout

Estoy haciendo un ejercicio en el que ingreso grados Fahrenheit y los convierto a Celsius. En la segunda pantalla me aparece el resultado, pero quiero ponerle un `textView` que diga "El resultado es" y no lo consigo. ¿Necesito crear otro archivo xml o preciso también pasar como parámetro así como pasé el valor que obtuve en la fórmula?

```
/* CODIGO JAVA DEL SEGUNDO ACTIVITY */

public class SecondActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    TextView resultado;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

        resultado= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resultado);// Acá esta el texto 
                                                           //que dice el 
                                                           //resultado es, pero
                                                           //no aparece :/

        String valor=getIntent().getExtras().getString("clave");

        ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.resultado)).setText(valor);

    }
}
```

XML DEL 2ND ACTIVITY:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              tools:context="com.example.brenda.celsius_a_farenheit.SecondActivity">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/resultado"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/resultado" />
</LinearLayout>
```

STRING XML

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name"></string>
    <string name="Etiqueta_datos">Ingrese temperatura</string>
    <string name="Boton">Click para ver el resultado</string>
    <string name="resultado">El resultado es: </string>
</resources>
```

Comment: Buenas @Brenda, podrías concatenar tu valor con el string que necesites al final por ejemplo  `((TextView)findViewById(R.id.resultado)).setText("El resultado es: "+valor);`, esto lo es una idea que puede ser mejorada, y respecto al comentario de porque no aparece el texto "El resultado es:" es porque lo estas remplazando por el dato en la variable valor.

Comment: Funcionó Perfecto @Nicethunder, Muchas Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

En este caso el valor del TextView esta en strings, hay que referenciarlo de esta forma:

```
resultado.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.resultado)+" "+valor);
```

La otra forma como ya comentaron es concatenando, en este caso no es necesario que
el valor del TextView este en values/strings:

```
resultado.setText("El resultado es: "+valor);
```